# Why does this statement print this output?

Tags: java

Why does this print statement print 3 and not 1004 as the output?

```
int n = 2005;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
   n = (n + 3) / 2;

System.out.print(n);
```

if I do this:

```
int n = 2005;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
System.out.println(n); 
n = (n + 3) / 2;
System.out.print(n);
```

It prints 2005 for each iteration and 1004, for the last time.

If there was brackets (like below)

```
int n = 2005;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        System.out.println(n); 
        n = (n + 3) / 2;
    }
    System.out.print(n);        
}
```

then it behaves like 2005
    1004
    503
    253
    128
    65
    34
    18
    10
    6
    4
    3
    3....3

Comment: You're performing the `n = (n + 3 / 2)` statement *50 times*. So after 1 iteration it's 1004, then it's 503, then it's 253, then it's 128 etc. What did you think the `for` loop was doing? Did you try debugging?

Comment: Also you might want use { } around loops.

Comment: Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: +1 for a much improved question, post edit.

Comment: Thanks. The question wasn't as simple as it first looked but I didnt explain the problem very clearly first time.

Answer (score 2):

Print `n` inside the `for` loop then you will got how this work.

```
int n = 2005;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    System.out.println(n);
    n = (n + 3) / 2;
}
```

Comment: yeah i understand that but there are no brackets on my for loop. I will edit the post to explain a bit better.

Comment: @user3568042 it doesn't change anything that there is no brackets for your loop, the statement will still be executed each time
if you have `for (condition) instruction1; instruction2;` instruction1 will be executed each time, while instruction2 will be executed after the end of the loop

Comment: thanks-that's the explanation I was looking for. I was wondering why both statements were not executing every time.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into detail: You are more or less cutting `n` in half every time. Eventually `n` will approach 3. Then its `(3 + 3) / 2 == 3`. In fact, you would get there for most initial numbers given a long enough iteration.